# Im having some trouble finishing this program if anyone could help that would be great

Tags: java

**This is the question For conversions between Kelvin and Fahrenheit temperatures use the conversion methods for conversion between Kelvin and Celsius, and between Celsius and Fahrenheit. Modify the main() method to include test cases for the new methods added.**

```
package projectTwo;
public class projectTwo {

    public static double f2c(double fahrenheit)
    {
        return 5.0 / 9.0 * (fahrenheit - 32.0);
    }

    public static double c2f(double celsius)
    {
        return 9.0 / 5.0 * celsius + 32.0;
    }
    public static double k2c(double kelvin)
    {        
        return 5.0 / 9.0

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.printf("%.2f F => %.2f C%n", 32.0, f2c(32.0));
        System.out.printf("%.2f F => %.2f C%n", 212.0, f2c(212.0));
        System.out.printf("%.2f C => %.2f F%n", 0.0, c2f(0.0));
        System.out.printf("%.2f C => %.2f F%n", 100.0, c2f(100.0));
    }

}
```

This is what I got im stuck.

Comment: Which part did you get stuck? You are already doing what the question asks.

Comment: Do you have a question? Also this appears to be an academic assignment question, which is generally frowned upon on SO

Comment: Maybe you need a `\n` instead of `%n` ---> `System.out.printf("%.2f F => %.2f C%n", 32.0, f2c(32.0));`

Comment: @AdmiralAdama There's no particular problem with homework. It just has to conform to the same standards as any other question--like being a specific question and not asking the community to write the poster's code.

Comment: 1. Does your code compile? I think it does not. 2. Do you have test cases? I think you may have some errors in your calculations. 3. What is your question?

Comment: @AdmiralAdama I reaching out because im stuck. I figured this was a good website for some answers. I guess SO is not a website designed to help of java programmers.

Comment: The code does compile, but the program is not finsished.

Comment: the out put is 32.00 F => 0.00 C
212.00 F => 100.00 C
0.00 C => 32.00 F
100.00 C => 212.00 F

Comment: 32.00 F => 0.00 C
212.00 F => 100.00 C
0.00 C => 32.00 F
100.00 C => 212.00 F

Comment: @chrylis true, good points. This seems to be the entire assignment with no directed trouble or what has been tried etc.

Comment: Not a coding issue, but 0 Kelvin is -273 C. I don't see the constant 273 in your code.
So to convert from Kelvin to Fahrenheit, if you don't want to do it directly, you have to first convert Kelvin to C (subtract 273) and then use the existing c2f.

Comment: Ok thanks Ill work on it.

Comment: I dont want you to solve this problem i just want some guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You have a wrong couples of `{}`. There is one ending `}` missing in the end of your `public static double k2c(double kelvin)` method. It's maybe a typo and there is no syntax error in your code but please fix it anyway.

---

Another mistake is while printing a new line. You have to use `\n` (not `%n` as you have used). So your code should look like this:

```
System.out.printf("%.2f F => %.2f C\n", 32.0, f2c(32.0));
System.out.printf("%.2f F => %.2f C\n", 212.0, f2c(212.0));
System.out.printf("%.2f C => %.2f F\n", 0.0, c2f(0.0));
System.out.printf("%.2f C => %.2f F\n", 100.0, c2f(100.0));
```

Answer (score 0):

package gradedhomeworkproject;
public class GradedHomeworkProject {

```
public static double f2c(double fahrenheit)
{
    return 5.0 / 9.0 * (fahrenheit - 32.0);
}

public static double c2f(double celsius)
{
    return 9.0 / 5.0 * celsius + 32.0;
}
public static double k2c(double kelvin)
{        
    return 5.0 / 9.0 * kelvin;
}    
public static double c2k(double celsiusx)
{
    return (9.0 / 5.0 - 273.15) - 1.8; 
}  

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.printf("%.2f F => %.2f C%n", 32.0, f2c(32.0));
    System.out.printf("%.2f F => %.2f C%n", 212.0, f2c(212.0));
    System.out.printf("%.2f C => %.2f F%n", 0.0, c2f(0.0));
    System.out.printf("%.2f C => %.2f F%n", 100.0, c2f(100.0));
    System.out.printf("%.2f K => %.2f C%n", 273.16, k2c(0.0));
    System.out.printf("%.2f C => %.2f K%n", 0.0, c2k(-273.16));
}
```

} 
"This is what I have so far now."

Answer (score 0):

package morejava;
public class MoreJava {
    public static double f2c(double fahrenheit)

```
{
    return 5.0 / 9.0 * (fahrenheit - 32.0);
}

public static double c2f(double celsius)
{
    return 9.0 / 5.0 * celsius + 32.0;
}
public static double c2k(double celsiusX)
{        
    return celsiusX + 273.15;
}
public static double k2c(double kelvin)
{
    return kelvin - 273.15;
}  
public static double f2k(double fahrenheitX)
{        
    return (fahrenheitX + 459.67) * 5.0 / 9.0;
}      
public static double k2f(double kelvin)
{        
    return kelvin * 9.0 / 5.0 - 459.67;
}       
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.printf("%.2f F => %.2f C%n", 32.0, f2c(32.0));
    System.out.printf("%.2f F => %.2f C%n", 212.0, f2c(212.0));
    System.out.printf("%.2f C => %.2f F%n", 0.0, c2f(0.0));
    System.out.printf("%.2f C => %.2f F%n", 100.0, c2f(100.0));
    System.out.printf("%.2f C => %.2f K%n", 0.0, c2k(0.0));
    System.out.printf("%.2f C => %.2f K%n", 100.0, c2k(100.0));
    System.out.printf("%.2f K => %.2f C%n", 273.15, k2c(273.15));
    System.out.printf("%.2f K => %.2f C%n", 373.15, k2c(373.15));
    System.out.printf("%.2f F => %.2f K%n", 32.0, f2k(32.0));
    System.out.printf("%.2f F => %.2f K%n", 212.0, f2k(212.0));
    System.out.printf("%.2f K => %.2f F%n", 273.15, k2f(273.15));
    System.out.printf("%.2f K => %.2f F%n", 373.15, k2f(373.15));
}
```

}
Im very proud to say I figured it out!

Answer (score -1):

You must close the method `public static double k2c(double kelvin)`

add a `}` and a semi colon after the return...

## Final Code:

```
package projectTwo;
public class projectTwo {

    public static double f2c(double fahrenheit)
    {
        return 5.0 / 9.0 * (fahrenheit - 32.0);
    }

    public static double c2f(double celsius)
    {
        return 9.0 / 5.0 * celsius + 32.0;
    }
    public static double k2c(double kelvin)
    {        
        return 5.0 / 9.0;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.printf("%.2f F => %.2f C%n", 32.0, f2c(32.0));
        System.out.printf("%.2f F => %.2f C%n", 212.0, f2c(212.0));
        System.out.printf("%.2f C => %.2f F%n", 0.0, c2f(0.0));
        System.out.printf("%.2f C => %.2f F%n", 100.0, c2f(100.0));
    }

}
```

## Output

[image]

Comment: Maybe OP needs a `\n` instead of `%n` ---> `System.out.printf("%.2f F => %.2f C%n", 32.0, f2c(32.0));`